# How do I create a mirror having multiple images in threejs?

Tags: three.js, geometry, aframe, mirror

I try the code of creating mirror in three.js from official website.
It uses Reflector.js which can show only one reflection of object.
I want to show multiple images when two mirrors are placed at different angles.
How can I achieve it?
Please help me.

The code of creating mirror is -

Mirror 1 -

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100 );
var verticalMirror = new THREE.Reflector( geometry, {
clipBias: 0.003,
textureWidth: WIDTH * window.devicePixelRatio,
textureHeight: HEIGHT * window.devicePixelRatio,
color: 0x889999,
recursion: 1
} );
verticalMirror.position.y = 50;
verticalMirror.position.z = - 50;
scene.add( verticalMirror );
```

Mirror 2 -

```
   var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100 );
    verticalMirror45 = new THREE.Reflector( geometry, {
            clipBias: 0.003,
            textureWidth: WIDTH * window.devicePixelRatio,
            textureHeight: HEIGHT * window.devicePixelRatio,
            color: 0x889999,
            recursion: 1
        } );
        verticalMirror45.rotateY(  Math.PI/ 1.33 );
        verticalMirror45.position.x = -15;
        verticalMirror45.position.y = 50;
        verticalMirror45.position.z =  -15;
        scene.add( verticalMirror45 );
```

Please help me.
Someone suggest me to use Aframe. Is it possible with Aframe? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead the [`mirror` component](https://github.com/alfa256/aframe-mirror-component) relying on [THREE.CubeCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/CubeCamera)